# Bash is not fully functional for a new user

Tags: bash, users, useradd

I just created a new user on my system using `useradd -d /home/users/john -m john` (Using Ubuntu 11.04). This worked fine, but when I changed to `john`, my bash is not fully functional. That is, it has no autocomplete, I can not use they arrow keys (e.g. UP to get the last command), and instead of showing my current directory it only shows `$`. I loaded a `.bashrc` but this appears to be completely ignored. What could cause this?

PD: this user is already working on the system and I rather not remove it and add it again, if possible.

Comment: Define what you mean by "when I changed to john".  Did you log in with that user at the main console, on a pty, through ssh, or did you `su` or `su -`?

Comment: What are the permissions/ownership on the .bashrc you loaded?

Answer (score 56, accepted):

Probably john's shell is not `/bin/bash`, but `/bin/sh`. On Ubuntu, that's a shell intended to execute scripts fast, with no fancy interactive features such as command line edition. Check last column of `grep john /etc/passwd` or `getent passwd john`. You might want to run `chsh -s /bin/bash john` to change user's shell.

Comment: Excellent, that was indeed the case!

Comment: Just a note. In Ubuntu `/bin/sh` is symbolic link to `dash` i.e. `/bin/dash`, so ultimately user's shell is `/bin/dash`.

Comment: I had to log out of all the users' sessions as well.

Answer (score 6):

you can jump between shells by typing the name of the shell

```
$ bash
```

and in the next line you will get this following prompt

```
user@hostname$
```

which is the bash shell. Your up arrow key and autocomplete will work now

Comment: It should be noted that is obviously temporary.  The currently accepted answer has a more permanent solution.

Comment: ok I didnt know that, thanks for that I will save the accepted answer for future reference